# Big O and Big Theta Equality

Tags: big-o, complexity-theory, theory

For example, I am asked the asymptotic complexity of building a binary heap (*the type of algorithm is arbitrary*) if I say an algorithm is `Θ(log(n))` would it also be correct to say that it is `O(n)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you're measuring the same quantity, anything that is Θ(log n) is also O(n). If the runtime is Θ(log n), then it's also O(log n) (that's part of the definition of Θ notation), and anything that's O(log n) is also O(n).

The case where you might have to be careful is if these are implicitly measuring different quantities. For example, if an algorithm's *best-case runtime* is Θ(log n), it doesn't necessarily follow that the algorithm's *worst-case runtime* will be O(n).

Comment: could you expand on what you mean by 'implicitly measuring different quantities'

Comment: It's for cases like what I was getting at in the second paragraph, where Theta(log n) and O(n) weren't measuring the same thing.